# subtract the different dimensional arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r

Let `A` and `B` be arrays, of dimension `[2,3,4]` and `[100,2]`, respectively. Note that `2` is the common dimension.

My desired answer is an array `C` of dimension `[100,2,3,4]` such that

```
C[h,i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] - B[h,i]
```

for all `h,i,j,k`.

Or

```
C[h,i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] + B[h,i]
```

for all `h,i,j,k`.

The later case is more easy to check the answer using the following example arrays.

---

E.g.,

```
    A <- array(NA,c(2,3,4))
    for (i in 1:2) {for(j in 1:3){for(k in 1:4){ 
A[i,j,k] <- i*1000000+j*100000+k*10000        
   }}}

    B <- array(NA,c(100,2))
    for (h in 1:100) {for(i in 1:2){B[h,i] <- h*10+i }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
C <- array(NA, c(dim(B)[1], dim(A)))
# Approach 1
for (h in 1 : dim(B)[1])
 for(i in 1 : dim(A)[1])
   C[h, i,, ] <-  A[i,, ] - B[h, i]

# Approach 2
for (h in 1 : dim(B)[1])  
 C[h,,,] <-  sweep(A, 1, B[h, ], "-")
```

To check if the answer is correct, pick some values for h, i, j, k

```
i <- 1; j <- 2; k <- 3; h <- 50

C[h, i, j, k]
#[1] 2338998

A[i,j,k] - B[h,i]
#[1] 2338998
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand your code, *vectorization* and minimal  `for loops` are used.  Thank you for reply.

Comment: Hope it helps. I added another answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I am studying the `sweep()`, I learn a lot from you. Thank you.